# The correct way to path files/images/links on html

Tags: php, html

It seems to be a very beginner question, but after finish my whole website, i found a "bug" on the structure of the path files/images and links.

Well, first let me tell you what is the exactly structure:

The website are located on: `/var/www`
Main pages files are located on the main website folder: `/www`
CSS files are located at `/www/styles/`
JS Files on `/www/js/`
Images on `/www/images/`

I have been writing my path of files/images with this current directory:
JS: `<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>`
Image: `<img src="images/img.jpg">`
Links: if i was point to the same file with get parameter, i just writed: `<a href="?parameter=test">`
Links for others files: `<a href="otherFile.php">`

Well, like i said, after some time i found a "bug". If i put / after .php link, for example: `example.com/test.php/`, all my images/js/css files break and all the href links become: `example.com/test.php/linkpage.php` instaed of `example.com/linkpage.php`.

So, i have now to change all my images/files and links with "/" in the beginning, to avoid this bug, like:

```
<a href="/linktopage.php">
```

It seems to fix the problem, but its the **correct** way to path these things?
I appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: what is the error shown previously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use / before links
like:
/otherFile.php
/images/img.jpg

this "/" load from www

**and your work is correct**

Answer (score 2):

1. Absolute paths starts in root folder with leading slash (`DocumentRoot = /var/www`)

   File on drive: `/var/www/mainfolder/subfolder/somepage.php`

   `<a href="/mainfolder/subfolder/somepage.php">`
2. relative paths starts in folder where you are, so if for an example you have script which url is in `mainfolder` - `http://domain.tld/mainfolder/myscript.php` and want to link the same use URL without slash and with relative path:

   `<a href="subfolder/linktopage.php">`
3. Finally you can also generate fully absolute links containing domain's name inside

   `<a href="http://domain.tld/mainfolder/myscript.php">`

#### Summary

1. This is best way for linking other pages or resources like JS, CSS and images. That makes sure that you won't need to fix your code when i.e. structure of your file changes, for an example, when you'll move the containing file into subfolder.
2. Relative paths are simple during writing, but has some disadventages when you need to change structure. Less benefits.
3. Fully absolute URL's are good option especially for resources that will be indexed by some search engines, like pages or public images, however in this case you should build these URL's programmatically like `$domain.'/some/asset.jpg'` otherwise you'll need to replace strings manually everytime, when domains changes.